# Create limit posting for users

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to make users only can create maximum 10 post per day.

Here is my controller:

```
$id_user=$this->session->userdata('id');
$sql ="SELECT COUNT(id_post) as max_post FROM post 
WHERE post.id_user=$id_user 
AND DATE(post.time)=DATE(NOW())";
$result = $this->db->query($sql);
if ($result > 10) //line number 17
{
  //redirect to home
} elseif($result <= 10 ) //line number 20
{ 
  //then do post
```

Then is getting error like this:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to int

Line Number: 17

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to int

Line Number: 20
```

Any answer?

Many thanks...

Comment: have made echo query?

Comment: What does `print_r($result)` give you? (*just after `$result = $this->db....`*)

Comment: try this one  if( $result[0]['max_post'] > 10)   {then your code here}

Comment: it showing error like this `Cannot use object of type CI_DB_mysql_result as array  `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($result > 10)
```

`$result` Is the resource itself, you have to fetch data from it. `$result` itself is not what you are looking for. Fetch the required field from result.

For example

```
$row = $result->row();
if ($row->max_post > 10)
```

Comment: i'm trying your code, it success in the first, but when i'm trying to upload in second time, it always redirect to home..

Comment: Thats some other problem then :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>10)
{

}
```

try using this

Comment: `$result` is class `CI_DB_mysql_result` object from Codeigniter active records. `mysql_num_rows($result)` over the `$result` will not work.

Comment: when i use '$q = mysql_query("select * from table");' and mysql_num_rows($q) then it works... what special in this case